# Fingerprint minutiae matching

Tags: image-processing, matlab, algorithms, fingerprint-recognition

I am working in a fingerprint recognition project using C code running on embedded system. After processing the fingerprint image, I have the minutiae now. I tried to matching two sets of minutiae by calculate the distance between each pair of minutiae and check if it is less than a threshold. But it seems not accurate.
So, is there another way/algorithm to match fingerprint minutiae? Please give me some document or source code. I dig around Google but there are theories, formulas and private matlab code ... I read them many times but I don't know how to implement them. I need something more clearly and easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get to obtain the minutiae? Then it's time to classify your minutiae and apply any proper machine learning technique for it. You want to reduce the matching universe when you need to detect a match.